# Wordpress: displaying an error message - hook admin_notices fails on wp_insert_post_data or publish_post

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, session, hook

I'm adding validation so if a post is in a particular category, it needs certain Custom Fields to be set.

This should be easy hooking `wp_insert_post_data` and `admin_notices`, but there is a redirect that causes the `admin_notices` callback to disappear.

OK - So I created a hack that uses the Session to store my error message across the redirect:

```
function set_post_pending($data, $postarr) {
    // If it's not valid...
        $error = "You are missing some Custom Fields.";
        $_SESSION['admin_notices'] = $error;
        $data['post_status'] = 'pending';
    return $data;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'set_post_pending',1,2);

function session_admin_notice() {
    if($out = $_SESSION['admin_notices']) {
        $_SESSION["admin_notices"] = "";
        echo $out;
    }
    return false;
}
add_action('admin_notices', "session_admin_notice");
```

The problem with this solution is that *some*how the session is not available when calling `session_admin_notice`, which has an easy (but *crazy*) solution:

```
public static function fix_session_bs() {
    // TODO: Why do I have to do this?
    if(!session_id() && $_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]) {
        session_start($_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]);
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'fix_session_bs');
```

The question is: Why do I have to go through all this craziness to throw an error message?

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress doesn't use sessions, and if `register_globals` is on it will clear the `$_SESSION` array.

Wordpress passes it's messages along using a `message` integer in the URL, an array of messages is then defined in the relevant `edit-[type]-form.php` file in the `wp-admin` folder. I think you could probably append your own variable to the redirect and then get that in your `admin_notices` hook function. Take a look at the `edit-[type]-form.php` files to get an idea of how this might work.

Answer (score 10):

You can simply do like WordPress do : using [transients](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) like this :

```
function set_post_pending($data, $postarr) {
    // If it's not valid...
        $error = "You are missing some Custom Fields.";
        set_transient( get_current_user_id().'missingfield', $error );
        $data['post_status'] = 'pending';
    return $data;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'set_post_pending',1,2);

function show_admin_notice() {
    if($out = get_transient( get_current_user_id().'missingfield' ) ) {
        delete_transient( get_current_user_id().'missingfield' );
        echo "<div class=\"error\"><p>$out</p></div>";
    }
    // return false; // nothing to return here
}
add_action('admin_notices', "session_admin_notice");
```

*ps : avoid $_SESSION in WordPress, thx*

Answer (score 1):

```
if($out = $_SESSION['admin_notices']) { 
      $_SESSION["admin_notices"] = ""; 
      echo $out; 
}
```

This condition is always TRUE so it always reset your $_SESSION['admin_notices'] var

Comment: Not exactly - the assignment IS evaluated (as the value which was assigned), so it will return `false` if `$_SESSION['admin_notices']` is also `false` or `!isset()`. http://www.sitepoint.com/assignment-inside-a-condition/